# Remove index.php from URL, Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite, laravel-5

I saw a lot of examples and tried a lot of solutions without success!
I am trying to put my project to Ubuntu server with apache.

**everything its ok when I do :**

```
"/MYEXAMPLE/public/index.php/dashboard"
```

**But I want:**

```
"/MYEXAMPLE/public/dashboard"
```

And there is the problem!

> "The requested URL /MYEXAMPLE/public/dashboard was not found on this server."

My **apache server** has de mod_rewrite.

My project folders are:

```
     - MYEXAMPLE
     --------- server.php
     --------- public
     ----------------.htaccess.php 
     ----------------.index.php 
     ---------------- views
```

My .htaccess.php:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

INDEX.PHP:

```
<?php //


require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/autoload.php';


$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';


$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
        $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

I do not want to remove my views from public folder! When I use wamp server, everything ok, I do not need to use the index.php at the URL. Now I am trying to use the Ubuntu server, but the URL's are not working because I need index.php

Other example: If I access

```
/MYEXAMPLE/public/
```

**OR**

```
/MYEXAMPLE/public/index.php
```

It goes to homepage as I want. The problem his when I am trying to change to other page!

Any sugestions to solve the problem? Why everything is ok running with wamp and when I try to use the Ubuntu server, I need the index.php at the URL?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Laravel's doc root should be the public folder. Read the install notes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to remove index.php from laravel url ?? in ubuntu 14.04](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001521/unable-to-remove-index-php-from-laravel-url-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 3):

You need to [point web server to `public` directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access) and use normal URLs like `/dashboard` instead of `/public/index.php/dashboard`.

```
DocumentRoot "/path_to_laravel_project/public"
<Directory "/path_to_laravel_project/public">
```

Also, you can use this [working Apache virtual host configuration for Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37750239/changing-base-url-of-localhost):

```
<VirtualHost some.app:80>
    DocumentRoot "/path_to_laravel_project/public"
    ServerName some.app
    ServerAlias some.app

    <Directory "/path_to_laravel_project/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

there are two solution for this problem.
1.edit your .htaccess to

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]

RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
```

2.dont edit your code and only run in cmd

```
 php artisan serve
```

i offer you second solution for this problem